# Question on an example that $\Bbb E{(X\mid Y=y)}$ always exists, but $\Bbb E(X)$ doesn't

Tags: definite-integrals, conditional-probability

On page 18 of Conditional Measures and Applications(2005) by M.M.Rao, there is an example that $\Bbb E(X^n\mid Y=y)$ always exists, but $\Bbb E(X^n)$ doesn't. It is mentioned that

> $\Bbb E(X^n\mid Y=y)$ can't be a conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$, since (9)([Law of iterated expection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)) does not hold.

Here's the screenshot of the example:
[image]

I'm not sure whether it means that $\Bbb E(\Bbb E(X^n\mid Y)) <\Bbb E(X^n)$ in this example.

So much for the background.

The **question** can be simplified as:

Can we decide that whether $\int_{(0, +\infty)} y^{-\frac{1}{2}} (\int_{[0, +\infty)} x^{2m} e^{-x^{2}y}dx)dy$ is finite for $m \in {\Bbb Z}^+$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we decide <strike>that</strike> whether $\int_{(0, +\infty)} y^{-\frac{1}{2}} (\int_{[0, +\infty)} x^{2m} e^{-x^{2}y}dx)dy$ is finite for $m \in {\Bbb Z}^+$?

The change of variable $x\to z=x\sqrt{y}$ shows that the integral is $$\int_0^\infty y^{-1/2}\int_0^\infty z^{2m}y^{-m}\mathrm e^{-z^2}y^{-1/2}\mathrm dz\mathrm dy=\int_0^\infty y^{-1-m}\mathrm dy\cdot\int_0^\infty z^{2m}\mathrm e^{-z^2}\mathrm dz,$$
which is infinite for every $m\geqslant0$.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Hope you don't mind a follow-up question. Can we decide whether $\Bbb E(\Bbb E(X\mid Y)) = +\infty$, if $\Bbb E(X) = +\infty$ in general?

Comment: Most presentations of conditional expectations do not allow to consider $E(X\mid Y)$ when $X$ is not integrable, hence the question is moot. Note that the textbook in your question never mentions $E(X\mid Y)$ when $X$ is not integrable, only $E(X\mid Y=y)$.